# MongoDB nested groups aggregation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a set of data in mongodb that looks like this:

```
{_id: ObjectId(""), created: date, otherObjectId: ObjectId(""), amount: number}
```

Is it possible to write an aggregation by year, then by month, then by otherCollectionID? Something like this:

```
[{year: [{month: [{otherCollectionID: {amount: "$amount"}}]}
```

I am able to aggregate by year and month, but I am not sure how to add another group for the second object ID field.

```html
db.Collection.aggregate([
    {$match: {status: 'succeeded'}},
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          year: {"$year": '$created'},
          month: {"$month": '$created'},
          otherObjectId: "$otherObjectId"
        },
        count: {$sum: 1},
        amount: {$sum: '$amount'}
      }
    }, 
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$_id.year",
        "data": {
          $push: {
            month: "$month",
            count: "$count",
            amount: "$amount"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ])
```

The result of this is:

```html
{
    "_id" : 2020,
    "data" : [
        {
            "count" : 4,
            "amount" : 200
        },
        {
            "count" : 1,
            "amount" : 50
        },
    ... for other months
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you add your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

I actually got it after reading the mongo documentation a little further. Here is my query:

```html
db.Collection.aggregate([
    { $lookup: {
       from: "OtherCollection",
       localField: "otherObjectId",
       foreignField: "_id",
       as: "otherData"
    }},
    { $unwind: "$otherData" },
    { $project: {
      "_id": 1,
      "created": 1,
      "amount": 1,
      "otherObjectId": 1,
      "otherData.field": 1
    }},
    { $group: {
        _id: {
          year: {"$year": '$created'},
          month: {"$month": '$created'},
        },
        otherData: {
          $addToSet: "$otherData"
        },
        count: {$sum: 1},
        amount: {$sum: '$amount'}
      }
    }, 
    { $group: {
        _id: {year: "$_id.year", month: "$_id.month"},
        data: {
          $push: {
            count: "$count",
            amount: "$amount",
            otherData: "$otherData"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    { $sort: {
      "_id.year": 1,
      "_id.month": 1 
    }}
  ])
```

This will result in:

```html
"_id" : {
        "year" : 2015,
        "month" : 12
    },
    "data" : [
        {
            "count" : 7,
            "amount" : 70,
          "otherData" : []
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : {
        "year" : 2016,
        "month" : 1
    },
    "data" : [
        {
            "count" : 27,
            "amount" : 10000,
            "otherData" : []
        }
    ]
}
...
```